# ZF: Login Form Validation

Tags: php, zend-framework, validation

WHat's the best way/code in Login Form (Zend_Form) to display error message 'Login/password incorrect'?

I slowly begin to understand, that setting $this->setErrorMessage('Login/password incorrect') in form/init() is not enough and I somehow have to involve Validators to be able to see the message I set.

To which object should I bind this message and do I have to use validator or not? 
Thanks!

Update:

LoginAction() code:

```
$auth  = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$authAdapter =
$this->_getAuthAdapter($formData['userName'],$formData['password']);
$result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

if (!$result->isValid()) {
    //Problem: the line below doesn't display error message
    $form->addError('Username or password do not exist'); 
    $form->populate($formData);
    $this->view->form = $form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `Zend_Form_Decorator_FormErrors` decorator. As this decorator is not registered by default on the `Zend_Form` you have to register the decorator manually.

You have to do something like this in your form's `init()` method:

```
$this->setDisableLoadDefaultDecorators(true);
$this->setDecorators(array(
    'FormElements',
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dl', 'class' => 'zend_form')),
    'FormErrors',
    'Form'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually have just two checks to cover my authentication forms.

1. Check username and password, and if either is not set, display a message like "Please enter both username and password"
2. Validate credentials using Zend_Auth and display an error if they are invalid: "Invalid  username or password".

I normally just pass the message to the view in a variable, but you might find a [FlashMessenger](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger) useful.